# argmax function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to create a `one-line` function "argmax" using fold where I enter an anonymous/lambda function and a list. Then I apply the function to the list and get a new list based on the function. Now I get the maximum value of the second list and return the element from the first list which created the maximum value when applied to the function.

It should look like this:

Input: `argmax (\x -> mod x 5) [1,4,7]`

the second list should be: `[1,4,2]`

The Maximum element from the second list is 4 so it should return 4 from the first list, because `mod 4 5 = 4.`

So the output should be: `4`

Currently I have this:

```
argmax :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> a

argmax f xs = foldr max f xs
```

but it doesnt work for a anonymous function

I get this error: `No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer))`

I tried to change the type signature, but that did not help.

If someone could help me fixing my code, I would appreciate it

Thanks in advance! ^^

Comment: What should the output of `argmax (\x -> mod x 5) []` be?

Comment: Please do not create new accounts to re-ask questions you've already asked. We can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74642707/anonymous-lambda-function-for-max. This kind of behavior leads to much duplication of effort. If you've made progress but have a new question, ask a new question *showing the progress and the new problem* under the same account. If it's useful context, you can link to the previous question as well.